# how to use jspanel4 with angular 1.x?

Tags: angularjs

[JSPanel4](https://jspanel.de/) is one of the best JS packages to show a floating panel. On the other hand, it is zero dependency and can be used with other frameworks. [Here](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Floating-panel-for-angular-js) is an old approach to load a view with JSPanel. But this is about JSPanle, not JSPanel4.

How could I use JSPanel4 with angular 1.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all open a float panel with jsPanl as follow:

```
    jsPanel.create({
        theme: 'primary',
        headerTitle : 'my panel #1',
        position : 'center-top 0 58',
        panelSize : '400 400',
        contentSize : '450 250',
        headerControls: 'all',
        content : '<div>{{data}}</div>',
        callback : panelCalback 
    });
```

Where the panelCalback is a function:

```
function panelCalback() {
    //1- convert to angular element
    var element = angular.element(this.content);

    // 2- compile the element
    var link = $compile(element);

    // 3- create panel controller
    var wbFloat = {
            hide: function(response) {
                panel.close();
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            cancel: function(response) {
                panel.close();
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
    };

    //4- load controller
    var childScope = $rootScope.$new(false, $rootScope);
    $controller('ControlerName', {
        $scope : childScope,
        $element : element,
        $wbFloat : wbFloat
    });
    link(childScope);
}
```

It converts the element into an angular element and then compiles it with a controller and isolated scope.